# How do I change the Bundle name of a Xcode project through command line?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I would like to that as it allows me to automate my build. Is there any way to achieve this?

Nvm i found the answer myself

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Your question is not constructive. Try to edit or delete it.